# How to take a log snapshot through Logger class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging

I use Ruby's logger class from the standard library.

I need to print the program log to a different report (some kind of snapshot)
but I can't access the content of the logger or find any way to access the file through the Logger instance.

My solution is to keep a pointer to the file when I initialize the logger and then access it later, 
But I don't need it all the time and keeping that seems redundant.
There must be a more elegant way to address the problem (though I can't find it)

I want something like:

```
class MainClass
    @@logger = nil
    def self.log_to(file_log_device)
        @@logger = Logger.new(file_log_device)
    end 
end
```

...program runs and logging using @@logger...

```
def take_log_snapshot
    snapshot_file = File.open("snapshot.txt",'wr')
    MainClass.logger.flush(snapshot_file)   
end
```

I want that the current data that spilled to the device (logging file) will be flushed also to snapshot_file

Comment: What would it do if the log device is `/dev/null` or `/dev/stderr` etc?

Comment: `MainClass.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logdev).dev` is the log device / file.